# when button clicked send post-id inside variable

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I have a query that displays events and there is a buy now button.
How do I make that when I press this button I send in a php session the post-id of the post that this button is inside of.
With what I have done so far the problem is that when I press the button I get the variable of the post-id of the last post in the loop instead of the post-id of the button I am pressing.

This is my code:

```
function calendario_posts(  ) {
    ob_start();


// WP_Query arguments


$paged = (get_query_var(‘paged’)) ? get_query_var(‘paged’) : 1;
$args = array (
    'category_name'          => 'calendario',
    'posts_per_page'         => '6',
    'paged' => $paged
);


// The Query
$featured_post_query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $featured_post_query->have_posts() ) {
    while ( $featured_post_query->have_posts() ) {
        $featured_post_query->the_post();

        ?>
                        <div class="teatro-all">
                            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(gallery); ?></a>
                            <h2 class="teatro-group teatro-title"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                            <h5 class="teatro-group teatro-fecha"> <?php the_field('fecha'); ?></h5>
                            <h5 class="teatro-group teatro-precio" >Precio desde: <?php the_field('precio'); ?></h5>
                            <?php $eventTitle = get_the_title(); ?>
                            <center><a class="teatro-buy teatro-button" href="http://localhost/newiga/tickets/">COMPRAR</a><br>
                            <center><a class="teatro-read-more teatro-button" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">LEER MAS</a></center> 
                            <script> var buybutton = document.getElementById("teatro-buy"); 
                                buybutton.onclick = function(){
                                        <?php $_SESSION['eventId'] = get_the_ID();?>
                                }
                        </script>

                        <?php
             }
}    else {
    // no posts found
    }



// Restore original Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
}

function calendario_shortcode() {

$output = calendario_posts();

$output = ob_get_clean();
    return $output;
}
add_shortcode( 'calendario', 'calendario_shortcode' );
```

Comment: Every time you iterate through your while loop, you are rewriting the $_SESSION variable over and over, which will result in only the last version of it being available.  Why are you using a $_SESSION variable with this?

Comment: Its a website to book tickets for a theatre and choose seaating after you press the button should take you to the page where you choose your seating and then with the event id it verifies in the databse which seats are free and blocks the ones that are not...